# DOJO cross-domain call returns data but fails due to syntax error in the Script tag

Tags: javascript, dojo, cross-domain

I am experimenting with a cross-domain call from Javascript, using the DOJO library. The web service I am calling returns JSON.
I am using "dojo.io.script.get" for this purpose. 
The web service does not establish any particular query string parameter for the callbackParamName so I'm using ar arbitrary name such as "callback".
DOJO will inject back the SCRIPT tag with the result as seen below (extracted from Firebug):

```
<script id="dojo_request_script0" type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8281/services/TestGeocodeWorldLocator.TestGeocodeWorldLocatorHttpSoap12Endpoint?format=json&callback=dojo.io.script.jsonp_dojoIoScript1._jsonpCallback" async="" charset="utf-8">

{"GeocodeAddressResponse":{"Result":{"PropertyArray":{"PropertySetProperty":[{"Key":"Shape","Value":{"X":"-8841758.9684124179","Y":"5474103.2948672064","SpatialReference":{"WKT":"PROJCS[\"WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_WGS_1984\",DATUM[\"D_WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS_1984\",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"Auxiliary_Sphere_Type\",0.0],UNIT[\"Meter\",1.0],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",3857]]","XOrigin":"-20037700","YOrigin":"-30241100","XYScale":"10000","ZOrigin":"-100000","ZScale":"10000","MOrigin":"-100000","MScale":"10000","XYTolerance":"0.001","ZTolerance":"0.001","MTolerance":"0.001","HighPrecision":"true","WKID":"3857"}}},{"Key":"Status","Value":"M"},{"Key":"Score","Value":"100"},{"Key":"Match_addr","Value":"1145 Nicholson Rd, Newmarket, ON, L3y"},{"Key":"PreType","Value":""},{"Key":"City","Value":"NEWMARKET"},{"Key":"Addr_type","Value":"StreetAddress"},{"Key":"X","Value":"-79.426873000000001"},{"Key":"Y","Value":"44.055940999999997"},{"Key":"Side","Value":"R"},{"Key":"House","Value":"1145"},{"Key":"PreDir","Value":""},{"Key":"StreetName","Value":"NICHOLSON"},{"Key":"SufType","Value":"RD"},{"Key":"SufDir","Value":""},{"Key":"Province","Value":"ON"},{"Key":"Postal","Value":"L3Y"},{"Key":"Disp_Lon","Value":""},{"Key":"Disp_Lat","Value":""},{"Key":"Loc_name","Value":"CAN_Streets"}]}}}}

</script>
```

The problem is that the browser (IE or Firefox) complains about 'Syntax Error - Expected ";"'. Basically it does not like the colons ":" in the JSON response injected in the SCRIPT tag.
Codewise, Javascript crashes at this line:
load: function(response, ioArgs)

I am thinking it may have something to do with the callbackParamName...but the server does not require any specific name. 
Can someone please suggest how can I solve this problem?

This is the code I am using:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src='dojo-release-1.8.0-src/dojo/dojo.js' data-dojo-config='parseOnLoad: true, isDebug:true'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

dojo.require("dojo.io.script");

   function DOJOtoWS() {

       var targetNode = dojo.byId("results");

       var jsonpArgs = {

         url: "http://localhost:8281/services/TestGeocodeWorldLocator.TestGeocodeWorldLocatorHttpEndpoint",             
         callbackParamName: "callback",             
         content: {format : "json"},                         
         load: function(response, ioArgs){

           console.log(response);
           return response;

           // Set the data from the search into the viewbox in nicely formatted JSON
           targetNode.innerHTML = "<pre>" + dojo.fromJson(response) + "</pre>";

         },
         error: function(response, ioArgs){
           targetNode.innerHTML = "An unexpected error occurred: " + response;

           console.log("error");
           console.log(response);
           return response;
         }
       };
       dojo.io.script.get(jsonpArgs); 
  }

  dojo.ready(DOJOtoWS);
```

Comment: FYI: dojo.io.* was deprecated. Use the new dojo/request/* module instead: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/releasenotes/migration-2.0.html

Answer (score 0):

**What you are describing sounds like [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). Thus the server needs to send data in JSONP format, not JSON.**

There is a syntax error in the script injected by Dojo because `dojo.script.io` is expecting the server to return results in this format:

```
callback({"GeocodeAddressResponse": "blah blah blah"});
```

*Explanation:* Internally Dojo constructs a function named "callback" so it can execute the JSONP sent from the server. This function processes the data and sends it to your `load` function. Verify by trying a server that sends data back in JSONP format like [this example](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/io/script.html) does (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web).

**Workarounds:**

If you can't control the format returned by the cross-domain server, you will have to either set up a cross-domain proxy on the same-origin server or configure your browser to allow cross-domain AJAX calls.

You may also want to investigate [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control) which is a new, safer standard meant to replace JSONP.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will look into setting up a proxy to solve the cross-domain issue.